# Removes a word from a dataframe column based on a specific word list .txt

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, loops

I have a specific dataframe column like the one below.

```
Index Positif 
1     keren banget mobilnya
2     bagus kendaraannya keren deh
3     mobilnya baik jalannya
4     suara mesinnya indah dan baik
```

and I have a list of words based on .txt contains.

```
keren
bagus
baik
indah
```

I want the columns only to contain the specific words that are based on the .txt file and desired output.

```
Index Positif 
1     keren 
2     bagus keren
3     baik
4     indah baik
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
words = ["keren", "bagus", "baik", "indah"]

df["Positif"] = df.index.map(
    df["Positif"]
    .str.extractall("(" + "|".join(words) + ")")
    .groupby(level=0)
    .agg(" ".join)[0]
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Index      Positif
0      1        keren
1      2  bagus keren
2      3         baik
3      4   indah baik
```